# HttpServletResponseWrapper java.lang.ClassCastException using Java 4 and struts 1.3

Tags: java, servlets, struts-1

I am currently working on a Legacy System. The system is using Java 4 and Struts 1.3. Well they're security is strict. Anyway

I was asked to create a logger for the request and response for their system. The idea is to have some audit for their new user interface and feature if there is a customer complain we can trace what happened by the logged request and response.

The idea is not to put a log on every module. Since they're using struts 1.3 my initial proposal is implement a module using Servlet Filter, ActionServlet or Requestprocessor. I have tried Servlet Filter but it can't work because they're web.xml is using http__java.sun.com_dtd_web_app_2.2.dtd. I have probelm find the 2.3 which is when Servlet Filter was introduced.

When I tried implementing a module using ActionServlet or Requestprocessor. I am atleast able to get the HttpServletRequest. However since this version of struts and java the HttpServletResponse really has no getter. I implemented a class that derives from HttpServletResponseWrapper.

When I used nothing is being received in the web browser. When I checked. I am getting a run time exception - java.lang.ClassCastException. I am not sure if HttpServletResponseWrapper can only be used with Servlet Filter or the library I have is old.

Basically this how I used in the Action Servlet.

```
public void doGet (HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException
{

       responseCapture = new M2UResponseWrapper((HttpServletResponse) response);

        try
        {

            super.doGet(request, responseCapture);

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Logger.error("Exception Type 1 : " + e);
        }


    }
```

Below is my `HttpServletResponseWrapper` implementation. This is just my initial test.

```
public class MyResponseWrapper extends HttpServletResponseWrapper {

private final HttpServletResponse httpResponse;

private int responseStatus;
private String errMessage;
private String redirectURL;
private ArrayList responseCookieList;
private Map responseDateHeader;
private Map responseHeader;
private Map responseIntHeader;

protected M2UServletOutputStreamWrapper output;
protected CharArrayWriter charWriter;
protected PrintWriter writer;
protected boolean getOutputStreamCalled;
protected boolean getWriterCalled;

public M2UResponseWrapper (HttpServletResponse httpResponse) {
    super(httpResponse);
    this.httpResponse = httpResponse;
    getOutputStreamCalled = false;
    getWriterCalled = false;
    charWriter = new CharArrayWriter();
    output = new M2UServletOutputStreamWrapper();
    responseCookieList = new ArrayList();
    responseDateHeader = new HashMap();
    responseHeader = new HashMap();
    responseIntHeader = new HashMap();
}

public String toString() {
  return charWriter.toString();
}

public boolean containsHeader(String name) {
    return httpResponse.containsHeader(name); 
}

public void addIntHeader(String name, int value) {
    responseIntHeader.put(name, Integer.toString(value));
    httpResponse.addIntHeader(name, value);
}

public void addDateHeader(String name, long date) {
    responseDateHeader.put(name,String.valueOf(date));
    httpResponse.addDateHeader(name,date);
}

public void addHeader(String name, String value) {
    responseHeader.put(name,value);
    httpResponse.addHeader(name, value);
}

public void setDateHeader(String name, long date) {
    responseDateHeader.put(name,String.valueOf(date));
    httpResponse.setDateHeader(name, date);
}

public void setHeader(String name, String value) {
    responseHeader.put(name,value);
    httpResponse.setHeader(name, value);
}

public void setIntHeader(String name, int value) {
    responseIntHeader.put(name, Integer.toString(value));
    httpResponse.setIntHeader(name, value);
}

public Iterator getHeader() {
    return responseHeader.keySet().iterator();
}

public Iterator getDateHeader() {
    return responseDateHeader.keySet().iterator();
}

public Iterator getIntHeader() {
    return responseIntHeader.keySet().iterator();
}

public void sendError(int sc) throws IOException {
    responseStatus = sc;
    try {
        httpResponse.sendError(sc);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void sendError(int sc, String msg) throws IOException {
    responseStatus = sc;
    errMessage = msg;
    try {
        httpResponse.sendError(sc, msg);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void setStatus(int sc) {
    responseStatus = sc;
    httpResponse.setStatus(sc);
}

public void setStatus(int sc, String sm) {
    responseStatus = sc;
    errMessage = sm;
    httpResponse.setStatus(sc, sm);
}

public String getErrorMessage() {
    return errMessage;
} 

public int getStatus() {
    return responseStatus;
}

public String getRedirectURL() {
    return redirectURL;
}

public void sendRedirect(String location) throws IOException {
    responseStatus = 302;
    redirectURL = location;
    try {
        httpResponse.sendRedirect(location);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public  void addCookie(Cookie cookie) {
    responseCookieList.add(cookie);
    httpResponse.addCookie(cookie);
}

public ArrayList getCookie() {
    return responseCookieList;
}

public PrintWriter getWriter() throws IOException{

    if (getOutputStreamCalled) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("getOutputStream() has already been called on this response.");
    }

    try {
        if (writer != null) {
            writer = new PrintWriter(charWriter);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    getWriterCalled = true;

    return writer;
}

public boolean isOutputStreamCalled() {
    return getOutputStreamCalled;
}

public boolean isWriterCalled() {
    return getWriterCalled;
}

public ServletOutputStream getOutputStream() throws IOException {   

    if (getWriterCalled) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("getWriterCalled() has already been called on this response.");
    }

    getOutputStreamCalled = true;

    return (ServletOutputStream) output;
}

}
```

I have seen many example that HttpServletResponseWrapper is used to get HttpServletResponse but they are all implemented in the Servlet Filter. I don't know if I really can't use HttpServletResponseWrapper on Action Servlet or Requestprocessor because Servlet Filter the request and response are ServletRequest and ServletResponse objects.

Please note I am working on legacy system so upgrading to struts 3 or spring or using java web app 2.3 and above dtd is not really an option. I am just hoping I made a mistake with my wrapper implementation. If you guys have other suggestion.

I did pitch in to them I will use command shell run an admin sniffing tool for the logging. It was immediately rejected.

Comment: [Please add a minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if its correct to post another question here. But I have found out what is wrong. The cast exception is originating from Broadvision version 6. It seems it has problem with HttpServletResponseWrapper. Does anyone have experience developing applications on broadvision, the documents I have on hand here, I believe is not complete.

I need maybe an example on how to create broadvision filter. I saw in on pdf that there is a broadvision filter but it mentions about creating a filter.xml which is similar to web.xml. But did not go into detail about what are methods that can be exploited in the broadvision filter class which I think is similar to Servlet Filter. It did not mention the sequence that will be followed like which has precedence the one in web.xml or filter.xml.